# Spanish Babel and cell alignment with percentage symbol

Tags: tables, babel, spanish

I realized that `spanish` option for the `babel` package produces a bad behavior of the percentage symbol when aligning cells of the tables.

This code produces the following table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \% & \% header & header \% \\
        \hline
        xxxxxxxxxxx & xxxxxxxxxxx & xxxxxxxxxxx \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Table OK]

But, adding the Spanish `babel` package prduces this:
This code produces the following table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \% & \% header & header \% \\
        \hline
        xxxxxxxxxxx & xxxxxxxxxxx & xxxxxxxxxxx \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Table OK]

What's going on? Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: Did you look into the documentation? In chapeter 1 ther  is something about a change in environment (of a.o. \%), but as the documentation is only available in Spanish I don't understand it.

Comment: Thank you. It seems the package adds a small space in front of the symbol, but I do not see the reason why the above happens. Anyway, using `\percentsign`instead of `\%` solved it.

Comment: Even when a small space in front of it I don't think this problem should appear, my internal knowledge of LaTeX is not enough to see why and how to fix it but it looks like a bug to me. Please correct me when I'm wrong.

Comment: I had a small further look in the documentation and I think you refer to paragraph 5.2 of the documentation where some things are written about some special characters. Problem looks like it only occurs when the % is the first character, so still I think my previous comment is valid.

Comment: Yes, that's my impression too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `babel-spanish`, `\%` is redefined to first do `\es@sppercent`, which in turn starts doing `\unskip`.

In your context, this cancel the centering glue from the column template, so the centering glue on the other side pushes everything all the way left.

A possibly better definition of `\es@sppercent` is to issue `\unskip` only when the *natural width* of the preceding glue is positive, for instance with

```
10 \%
```

that the conventions want to be typeset with a thin space and not a normal space. We can check just the natural width with `\ifdim\lastskip>\z@`. This way, `\fill` glue will not be removed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\es@sppercent{%
  \leavevmode
  \ifdim\lastskip>\z@ \unskip\fi
  \textormath{$\m@th\,$}{\,}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\% & \% header & header \% \\
\hline
xxxxxxxxxxx & xxxxxxxxxxx & xxxxxxxxxxx \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A possibly better approach is to remove the glue only if it has no infinite stretchability:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\es@sppercent{%
  \leavevmode
  \ifnum\gluestretchorder\lastskip=\z@\unskip\fi
  \textormath{$\m@th\,$}{\,}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\% & \% header & header \% \\
\hline
xxxxxxxxxxx & xxxxxxxxxxx & xxxxxxxxxxx \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would your recommendation be that your redefinition would be incorporated into the Spanish babel version?

Comment: @albert I've already mailed the maintainer for this issue.

Comment: Perfect (so I don't have to submit an issue anymore).

Comment: Thank you! I guess I just found my first bug in Latex... So proud of myself :)

Comment: @AugSB Yes, you found a bug :). I'll fix it.